# Best way to construct a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

First I want to throw out I am still pretty new to SQL.

Consider you have a table with columns x and y, where both are positive integers.

Question 1:

What is the best way to find if a specified `y` value `i` exists for all `x` values?

Question 2:

What is the best way to find if a specified `y` value `i` exists for each `x` in a set of `x` values of size p?

I found a way where I do n number of self joins for the first case or p self joins for the second. But am curious of better ways to accomplish this.

An example table:

```
x,y
---
1,a
1,b
2,a
3,b
3,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is correct: Using a heap of joins is very *inefficient*.
Here's the efficient way:

Question 1: These two values will be the same if the premise is true

```
select 
    (select count(distinct x) from t1 where y = '1') as x_count_with_y,
    (select count(distinct x) from t1) as x_count
```

Question 2: This value will be the same as the number of x in the set if the premise is true

```
select count(distinct x)
from t1
where y = '1'
and x in (1,2,3,5,8)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I figured there had to be a better way.